# Apply function to column A if conditional of corresponding (same index point) column B holds

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, boolean

I have a dataframe with a pricing info on 'close' column. I have indicators in 'BUY' and 'SELL' columns, which are booleans. I would like to apply a function to instance in 'close' column, if and only if the conditional for 'BUY' holds ie. when 'BUY' == 1, apply a function (return over a given period) to the corresponding 'close' value. I have added a picture that illustrates what I mean and shows the dataframe.

Thanks

[image]

```
3233  108.60  0.0   0.0
3234  107.15  0.0   0.0
3235  106.70  0.0   0.0
3236  109.85  0.0   0.0
3237  107.45  0.0   0.0
3238  109.65  0.0   0.0
3239  107.25  0.0   0.0
3240  106.05  0.0   0.0
3241  101.00  0.0   0.0
3242  100.45  0.0   0.0
3243  100.75  0.0   0.0
3244   99.80  0.0   0.0
3245   96.70  0.0   0.0
3246   94.80  0.0   0.0
3247   94.05  0.0   0.0
3248   92.95  0.0   0.0
3249   93.55  0.0   0.0
3250   91.90  0.0   0.0
3251   91.25  1.0   0.0
3252   95.15  0.0   0.0
3253   93.80  0.0   0.0
3254   95.05  0.0   0.0
3255   95.80  0.0   0.0
3256  101.70  0.0   0.0
3257  106.90  0.0   0.0
3258  102.50  0.0   0.0
3259   96.75  0.0   0.0
3260  100.25  0.0   0.0
3261   98.00  0.0   0.0
3262   98.20  0.0   0.0
```

Comment: Why don't you copy and paste the sample data here? It helps ppl test their answers better.

Comment: I will add the tail of the data that has some conditionals within it. Thanks

Comment: The row 462 needs to have sell=1 right?

Comment: Nope. Will be making a slightly varied function for the SELL column when SELL=1, but will have the same premise/rules as BUY column.

Comment: And the function you want needs to work based on the most recent buy=1 ? or the first one like you show in your example? i.e. should the buy in row 452 or 453 be considered in the calculations for returns?

Comment: Needs to work on all instances where  buy=1 and then skip where buy=0.

Comment: You mean all instances of buy=1 before the date or index for which you are processing the return?

Comment: All instances of buy=1 throughout the entire dataframe

Comment: what will be your other input parameters to the returns method, apart from the close prices of the instances where buy=1?

Comment: Another close price at +n index points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will get the returns you want:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
        'Index':range(452, 464),
        'close':[113.05,112.05,111.45,114.20,109.45,110.50,109.65,114.4,110.15,110.90,112.25,117.75],
        'BUY':[1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
        'SELL':[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
})

def calculate_buy_returns(data, n):
    returns = []
    for i, row in data.iterrows():
        if row.BUY == 1:
            if  (i + n) < len(data):
                # get the close price at index + n
                close_n = data[data.index == (i + n)].iloc[0].close
                returns.append((close_n - row.close)/row.close)
            else:
                returns.append(0)
        else:
            returns.append(0)
    return returns

data['returns'] = calculate_buy_returns(data, 10)

print(data)
```

The output is:

```
    Index   close  BUY  SELL   returns
0     452  113.05    1     0 -0.007077
1     453  112.05    1     0  0.050870
2     454  111.45    0     0  0.000000
3     455  114.20    0     0  0.000000
4     456  109.45    0     0  0.000000
5     457  110.50    0     0  0.000000
6     458  109.65    0     0  0.000000
7     459  114.40    0     0  0.000000
8     460  110.15    0     0  0.000000
9     461  110.90    0     0  0.000000
10    462  112.25    0     0  0.000000
11    463  117.75    0     0  0.000000
```

Comment: This is perfect. I keep getting an error though: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Index'". Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: check if you have an explicit column named 'Index' in your dataframe like you have shown in your  example in your screenshot? if not, then change the line for setting close_n to this: close_n = data[data.index == (i + n)].iloc[0].close

Comment: One last thing. If I change the n in the function to anything greater than 11, I receive an 'IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds'. Idea how to fix this so that n can be completely ambiguous and have no constraints?

Comment: You need to make sure that the current index + n is not greater than the number of rows in the dataframe. You can find the number of rows of the dataframe using len(data)  and add a check for it.

Comment: Yes, the last instance of buy=1 is 12 rows from the end of the dataframe. Recommend making dummy rows to get it work for the instances that are within the proper n range?

Comment: It will depend on how do you want to handle that case. Maybe you can append 0 to the results list for that condition?

Comment: Would that be throwing an elseif statement into the function?

Answer (score 0):

Try [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```py
>>> def my_func(s):
...     if s['A']:
...         s['B'] = s['B'] ** 2
...     return s
... 
>>> thing = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False, True], 'B': [1, 2, 3]})
>>> thing.apply(my_func, axis=1)
       A   B
0   True   1
1  False   2
2   True  81
```

A warning though: this is much slower than you'd like. It removes all the speed you get from vectorized computations, because your function is not vectorized. If the next thing you plan on doing is pulling out exactly those modified values (like `results = thing[thing['A']]['B']`), you should just apply your function to the [masked](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking) Series:

```py
>>> thing[thing['A']]['B'] ** 2
0     1
2    81
Name: B, dtype: int64
```